# Should I have turned off mod_security?

Tags: mod-security

It probably took me too long, 4 hours, to figure out the real issue.  Some of my iPhone app's requests were getting through to my shared-hosting web server, and others weren't.  I finally pinned down that the difference was in the text contents of my POST headers.

My shared-host tech support enlightened me.  One of my requests contained the words "I'm **having** a good time" in a POST header from user input, and the server's mod_security module didn't like the word "having", apparently believing it was a security threat.

I mentally went ballistic.  This was an example of security run amok, trashing my app's requests (causing problems for my users) for a very stupid reason.  Tech support disabled that particular mod_security rule, but that left many others that could be equally stupid.

So I used cPanel to turn off mod_security entirely for all my sites.  My php script carefully sanitizes all user input, and it seemed like mod_security itself was the most serious threat to my app's proper performance.

Did I do the right thing?  Or will it bite me in the ass down the road?

Comment: "Tech support disabled that particular mod_security rule, but that left many others that could be equally stupid" Yeah you should totally ask them to disable `mod_php` :P

Comment: More serious yes it is safe to disable mod security.